# Condensing a DataFrame based on Matching Column Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a large project where I need to combine multiple dataframes to perform the rest of my analysis.  The issue is All other dataframes BUT one have a purely unique identifier set up as ZZZ-999.  The problem dataframe can, but not always, have two values set up as ZZZ-999 ABCD or ZZZ-999 EFGH.  An example of the fields

Main Dataframe (To have columns added to)

```
 Unit ID     |     Region        |  Unit Value
 ZZZ-997           East                 100
 ZZZ-998           West                 200
 ZZZ-999           South                300
```

DataFrame Needed to Combine with Main DataFrame

```
 Unit ID    |   Product Type   |  Individual Value  |  Final Disposition
 ZZZ-997         ZZZ-997 ABCD        50                    Returned
 ZZZ-997         ZZZ-997 EFGH        50                    Returned
 ZZZ-998         ZZZ-998 ABCD        200                   Order Closed
 ZZZ-999         ZZZ-999 ABCD        100                   Order Closed
 ZZZ-999         ZZZ-999 EFGH        200                   Returned
```

My Desired Outcome would be:

```
 Unit ID     |     Region        |  Unit Value |  Individual Value ABCD  |  Final Disposition ABCD  |  Individual Value EFGH |  Final Disposition EFGH
 ZZZ-999           South             300               100                       Returned                        200                 Order Closed
```

My attempt to do this involved pd.dataframe.iterrows() creating a loop through both dataframes and combined using a dataframe.loc() to permenantly add to the warehouse.  The issue is this takes a few seconds per row of data and I have over 100k rows of data.  What is the most efficient way to combine the dataset's as above.

Thank you for your time,

Best,

Andy

Comment: I'm still confused as to what the end goal of this join is, can you please clarify why that's your desired outcome? Why is it just the single Unit ID?

Comment: @wpercy I am only an operations analyst and have to work with the data given to me.  Essentially, what I am working with is Tissue which can be used one of two ways from the same source.  Due to this, the single ID represents the source, the Product ID represents the two types of tissue possible from the source.  Our analysis will provide the most detail at a Source level instead of the individual product types as we try and aggregate why a certain source caused a failure of one type but a passable quality for the other type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
df['Product Type']=df['Product Type'].str.split().str[1]
newdf=df.set_index(['Unit ID','Product Type']).unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
newdf.columns=newdf.columns.map(' '.join)
newdf=newdf.reset_index()
newdf
Out[814]: 
   Unit ID  Individual Value ABCD Final Disposition ABCD  \
0  ZZZ-997                   50.0               Returned   
1  ZZZ-998                  200.0           Order Closed   
2  ZZZ-999                  100.0           Order Closed   
   Individual Value EFGH Final Disposition EFGH  
0                   50.0               Returned  
1                    NaN                   None  
2                  200.0               Returned
```

After get the newdf , just do merge like `newdf.merge(main)` will yield the result

Comment: Ah, you're a rockstar Wen.  Exactly what I needed and the code is easy to understand why it works.

Comment: @A.McMaster Yw : -) happy coding